# How to switch user-space process back to the root network namespace?

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel, lxc

The problem is that *`/var/run/netns/`* directory contains all the network namespaces, except the  **root** namespace. So I am not sure, how to get the *`fd`*, that should be passed to the following kernel call:

```
syscall(__NR_setns, fd, CLONE_NEWNET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU, you can use `/proc/<pid>/ns/net`.

Comment: Yes, figured this out. Except the <pid> should be 1, not the current process (a.k.a /proc/self/ns/net).